# Recreating a layout in LaTeX (XeTeX), but I have some concerns

Tags: xetex, book-design

Apologies for not being able to make the title of this questions clearer.
I am trying to recreate a - lets say - 'book' layout in XeTeX, however I have some concerns.

Below I have a sketch of the layout I am trying to recreate (I hope it's clear, sketching is not my strong suit as a developer :)).

[image: Sketch of layout I'm trying to recreate]

It's a two-column twoside layout.

I have three concerns...

**Concern 1**

The blue highlight is a chapter header, however, this header is not placed in the body section where they would normally go. The smaller grey framework below it is, I assume, going to be the body.

The way I see it, I have 2 possible solutions:

1. Find some way to put chapter title's in the header.
2. Find some way to add a margin to pages without a chapter title.

I'm unsure how to go about this, any solutions?

**Concern 2**
The block marked in grey is a quote. However, this quote has a background color that starts from the left side of the page. Is there any way I can achieve this effect?

**Concern 2**
The X's on the 2 pages are the page numbers. They are a bit oddly placed, however. I tried using the `textpos` package to absolutely position them in the correct location, but I can't find a way to repeat this on every page.

====

I'm sure it would be possible to recreate this, but I would like to know if LaTeX is the way to go here. If the solutions are difficult/hacky I will look for other options for recreating this layout.

This is a big question, and might be a little difficult to understand, so please ask me if I need to clarify a bit more. I would greatly appreciate your thoughts!

Cheers!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Of course, LaTeX will do it, and well! However, you'll have to 'get your hand dirty', since what you want is really 'rendering-oriented'. I am not skilled enough to help you further, but for sure  there are skilled people nearby. Have you already tried something by yourself? If you show your trials, people would be more disposed to help you.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to have a look at the `KOMA script` classes, esp. `scrbook`. They provide a number of easy-to-use options to configure the page layout (the English manual is available via http://www.komascript.de/~mkohm/scrguien.pdf).

For example, using `KOMA`’s

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}

\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\clearscrheadfoot
\cehead{\textnormal{\small\leftmark}}
\lehead{\pagemark}
\cohead{\textnormal{\small\rightmark}}
\rohead{\pagemark}
```

you get, on facing pages, the page number on the outer limits of the head line (you can move it further outwards) and in the center the chapter heading on the left (even) and the section header on the right (odd) pages, respectively.

There are, of course, a couple of other possibilities to achieve this with other classes or packages.

---

Edit: Johannes is right, I was cutting things a bit short. I've updated the code snippet accordingly.

Comment: The commands you are using are not defined with `scrbook`. Changing the font and style of headers and footer is also done in a different way. Please have a look package `scrlayer-scrpage`.

Comment: Please do not post such fragments only!

Comment: Take a look at the `memoir` class (`texdoc memoir` or `texdoc memman`) which provides many solutions to book design problems.

Comment: @Johannes_B: I've updated the code as per your correct intervention that these are not defined in the class.
As for the other part, note that there is only `\addtokomafont{pagehead}{[style]}` for all header elements, and none for each of these. Fine tuning thus has to be done in the respective element itself.

Comment: There is one for the head in general, and another hook for the `\pagemark`.

Comment: While that is right, there are none for any of the `\..head` (or `\..foot`, FWIW)